# What does ending the if statement with a } do in javascript exactly?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For instance if I have an if statement that goes like this:

```
if(...) {
//some code
if(...) {
//somecode
}
}
```

how does it differ from:

```
if(..) {
//code
}
if(...) {
//cod
}
```

Comment: If you'd indent your code, the difference should be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is a nested if i.e.

```
if(condition1) {
    if(condition2) {
        statement1 ;
    }
    statement2 ;
}
```

This will execute `statemen1t` only when both `condition1` and `condition2` are true and `statement2` whenever `condition1` is true. The execution is as follows:

- First `condition1` is evaluated and checked. If it is true, the flow of control enters scope of first `if`.
- Now, `condition2` is evaluated and checked and if true, the flow of control enters scope of second `if` and `statement1` is executed.
- If it is false, then the flow of control does not execute `statement1`.
- Since there are no more `if`s inside the first `if`, the `statement2` is executed.
- If the first `condition1` itself is false, then nothing is executed.

The second one is two ifs, not related to one another i.e.

```
if(condition1) {
    statement1 ;
}

if(condition2) {
    statement2 ;
}
```

Here if `condition1` is true, `statement1` is executed and if `condition2` is true then `statement2` is executed. The two `if`s are not related in anyway. For that use an `if`-`else` ladder i.e.

```
if(condition1) {
    statement1 ;
}
else
if(condition2) {
    statement2 ;
}
```

In this case, `condition2` will be checked only if `condition1` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Without indentation could be easily mistaken, that's why indentation is so important. Basically the first code is:

```
if (conditionA) {
  // code A
  if (conditionB) {
    // code B 
  }
}
```

As you can see, "code B" will be executed only if both `conditionA` and `conditionB` are `true`.

In your second example, the two `if` statement are on the same level:

```
if (conditionA) {
  // code A
}

if (conditionB) {
  // code B
}
```

Therefore here the "code B" needs only `conditionB` to be `true` in order to be evaluated.